# Empty request_query field, no records in Page Query Terms report

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint-2010, statistics, iis-7.5, urchin

I have a problem that I can't find a solution for, even after hours of searching with google. I have an IIS 7.5 installed and Urchin 6 over a SharePoint 2010 application. I have a custom newsletter mechanism, that creates links in messages as follows:

```
http://somesite/newsletter/pages/newsletter17-20121018164411?NewsletterID=1&userLogin=USER&newslettersrc=http://site-to-redirect/site/pages/page.aspx
```

(when user enters the url is being redirected to url 'newslettersrc')

I thought I would be able to trace numbers of people who clicks a link from a newsletter and opens a webpage, by analyzing 'Page Query Terms' report. But I can't find any results there, for pages with name 'newsletter'. Moreover, as I checked using the Urchin form for API testing, value in field request_query for specified request_stem is empty. I also checked IIS logs, where I found that the URL is divided properly into cs-uri-stem and cs-uri-query, as follows:

- cs-uri-stem:

  ```
  http://mysite/newsletter/pages/newsletter17-20121018164411
  ```
- cs-uri-query:

  ```
  NewsletterID=1&userLogin=USER&newslettersrc=http://site-to-redirect/site/pages/page.aspx
  ```

What can be wrong? Other queries, generally some short variables and numeric values are stored properly, So why queries from newsletter are not stored in urchin database? Why, for this request_stems request_queries are empty? Has anyone faced such problem?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will read this question in future - the solution was easy - the URL string that is a parameter in another url string needs to be encoded. After doing this, Urchin will record it without any troubles.